# JQuery and Bootstrap pull function conflicts

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a static website. When you scroll down, a JQuery event listener triggers and a div slides from the right side of the screen into focus. Everything works fine... except the bootstrap styling after the event is complete. There are two subsections in the div. I want to pull the section from right to the left (for mobile adjust reasons) and vice versa. The push part goes to the right like it is supposed to, but the section I want on the left, the pull section, refuses to move. It stays on the right and ignores the Bootstrap pull styling. This is a problem. I don't know what to do. Can someone help?

Here is the section in question:

```
<div class="row section_3">
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-6">
        <%= image_tag 'pencil.jpg', class: 'picture left' %>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-5 col-xs-10 col-xs-push-1">
        <h2 class="darkgrey left">Did you know?</h2>
        <h4 class="content grey left">Due to an extreme lack of funding, many public schools have had to cut entire subjects from their ciriculum to make ends meet. Even after eliminating music and physical education programs, educators often have personally purchase basic classroom supplies to ensure their students have the tools they need.</h4>
        <div class="button-donate left">Learn More</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JQuery slide event:

```
function left() {
    pos = window.pageYOffset; 
    if (pos > 700) {
        $('.left').animate({left: '0px'}, 1200);
    }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', left);
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.left {
position: relative;
left: 6000px;
}
```

Here is an image of the issue.

[image]

Help! (thanks)

Comment: please give a working code

Comment: If you disable all JQuery and CSS other than Boostrap, the problem still occurs. Whatever it is, it looks like it is with this code.